# What techniques/tools are used to create this text motion graphics in After Effects?

Tags: after-effects, animation, motion-graphics

What tools or techniques do you think are used to create the following motion graphics in After Effects?
Do you think they are created using presents, plugins, expressions, or just by keyframing every step of the way? There is also Pins&Box script which could make similar results, but I am not sure.

[image]
[image]

Thanks for you response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text animators are an essential part of working with text in AE, I suggest you read up on them, [which you can do here.](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/animating-text.html) Text animators give you lots of tools for doing the kind of effects you want, but they're slightly unintuitive. However for the beginner there are dozens of presets included.

As far as the boxes go, it's a fairly simple animating task, that could be achieved with masks, matte layers, animated shape layers, a combination of the above, or probably a dozen other techniques. A good tip is to slow down the video you want to reproduce, and work out what exactly is going on frame-by-frame.

For example the *eat less junk food* text box starts as a series of boxes which you could create using shapes that have their scale animated, until they overlap and form a single box. Or perhaps you could have a single box that is revealed by a number of masks that are animated to grow.

The box is then split in two which you could achieve with another animated mask using the subtract masking mode that starts with zero width and grows until it covers the box completely. Notice that as this happens the green shape is growing slightly, so you animate its scale as well.

**TL;DR**: the plugin you need is called Animation™.

Answer (score -2):

these animations are called Lower thirds. You can achieve this by adding a mask layer to the text or by using a plugin.

There are 15 minute videos tutorials in youtube that explains every step of the animation.